# ServiceStack: Can we Pass Data through a RequestFilterAttribute to the calling service

Tags: authentication, servicestack, jwt, sitefinity

Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong, but I'm trying to create a custom attribute for our CMS to handle auth checks.

https://gist.github.com/sitefinitysteve/62ab761256a64a84d8a6#file-sitefinityjwt-cs-L39

So if this service is called from within the CMS from a logged in user, user data is all there for the service method already.

But in the context of being called from an app, the user is technically Anonymous, however I can decode the token and get the user just fine... but not sure how to like pass that over to the service.

Am I just maybe looking at this wrong, and the proper thing to do is to call a CMS API method to just log that person in (seems slow if I already have the persons user object from line 33, and the service context expires instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use Request.Items Dictionary

You would use the `IRequest.Items` dictionary for any data you want to pass throughout [ServiceStack's Request Pipeline](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations):

```
//RequestFilter:
req.Items["info"] = new MyRequestInfo { ... };
```

In Service:

```
var info = (MyRequestInfo)base.Request.Items["info"];
```

#### Have DTO's share common interface

Another option for adding extra info to your Service is to have Request DTO's implement an interfaces, e.g:

```
public interface IHasInfo
{
    MyRequestInfo Info { get; set; }
}
```

Which you could then populate in your Request Filter, e.g:

```
((MyRequestInfo)dto).Info = new MyRequestInfo { ... };
```

Access in Service like any other DTO property, e.g:

```
public object Any(Request request)
{
    var info = request.Info;
}
```